# Add an Extra Row to a Select with CTE Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below please find my select. The result of this select is as follows:

```
fecha1          columna_1       columna_2
09.07.2014     10.00000000     3.00000000
10.07.2014     12.20000000     5.06000000
11.07.2014     15.56600000     9.26240000
12.07.2014     20.18864000     27.35320192
15.07.2014     28.60184480     22.85988716
```

My question is: I want to add an extra row to the result of the select below. This row should include:

fecha1 = one day before the first day shown in the "fecha1" column

columna_1 =0

columna_2=0

Can I do this?

This is the actual select:

---

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE
(codigo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fecha DATE NOT NULL,
diferencia NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @sales(codigo, fecha, diferencia)
VALUES ('q', '20140708', 51),
('q', '20140712', 0.03), 
('q', '20140712', 0.033), 
('q', '20140712', 0.04), 
('q', '20140811', 0.03), 
('q', '20140812', 0.01),
('q', '20140815', 0.05),
('q', '20140815', 0.06),
('q', '20140815', 0.02),
('q', '20140114', 0.07),
('q', '20140714', 0.024),
('q', '20140714', 0.024),
('x', '20140709', 0.025),
('x', '20140710', 0.016),
('x', '20140711', 0.036),
('x', '20140712', 0.023),
('x', '20140712', 0.035),
('x', '20140715', 0.057),
('c', '20140709', 0.097),
('c', '20140710', 0.0197),
('c', '20140711', 0.0297),
('c', '20140712', 0.0397),
('c', '20140715', 0.071);


;with ctesource as 
(
    select
        codigo,diferencia,
        fecha,
        sum( log( 1e0 + diferencia ) ) over ( partition by codigo order by fecha rows unbounded preceding) as LogAssetValue
    from
        @sales
        WHERE codigo IN ( 'c', 'x') and fecha > DATEADD(month, -24, getdate())
)
select convert(varchar, fecha, 104) AS fecha1,  
 CAST(SUM(Case codigo when 'c' then (exp(LogAssetValue)-1)*100 ELSE 0 END) AS numeric(16, 8)) as columna_1,
 CAST(SUM(Case codigo when 'x' then (exp(LogAssetValue)-1)*100 ELSE 0 END) AS numeric(16, 8)) as columna_2
from ctesource 
GROUP BY fecha
order by fecha;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `varchar` in SQL Server *always* include a length.  One way to do what you want is with `union all`:

```
(select convert(varchar(255), fecha, 104) AS fecha1,  
        CAST(SUM(Case codigo when 'c' then (exp(LogAssetValue)-1)*100 ELSE 0 END) AS numeric(16, 8)) as columna_1,
        CAST(SUM(Case codigo when 'x' then (exp(LogAssetValue)-1)*100 ELSE 0 END) AS numeric(16, 8)) as columna_2
 from ctesource 
 GROUP BY fecha
) union all
(select convert(varchar(255), dateadd(-1, day, min(fecha)), 104),
        0, 0
 from ctesource
)
order by fecha1;
```